# How to fit more than 2000 items in a Select tag?

Tags: javascript, html-select

I'm trying to create a dropdown for cities. I'm getting the items from a database table, the items are about 3000 cities. When I load the page, it gets frozen. Is there a way to fit them all?

This is the Select Tag:

```
<select name="primary_address_city" id="primary_address_city" class = "city" maxlength='150' 
value='{$fields.primary_address_city.value}' tabindex="0">
</select>
```

This is the JS Code:

```
const selectcity = document.querySelectorAll(".city")

const getCityData = async () => {
const res = await fetch('test/city.php')
const data = await res.json()
return data
}

getCityData().then(data => {

    selectcity.forEach(address => {
        data.map(({ city }) => {
            return address.innerHTML += `
        <option value = ${city}>${city}</option>
        `
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: How many `option` elements can be used in a `select` depends on the browser and os. If you have to use such a large amount of items then there is probably no way around a library that creates a dropdown replacement for the native  `select` item.

Comment: This is terrible UX. Make it a search field instead, just thinking about scrolling a list that long sends shivers down my spine

Comment: Take a look at this library, I think it could solve your problem. https://select2.org/

Comment: @Daantje I use select2 at work (but an older version) it would work perfect for this situation, however, isn't there a dependency on using jQuery, or has that changed.

Comment: Select2 is a massive expense in terms of code footprint iirc, tho that may have changed since I last looked at it. There are far better ways of approaching this problem.

Comment: There is a vanilla port of it https://bluzky.github.io/nice-select2/ But, like others already mentioned, wouldn't a type-a-head or search field be better for this kind of data?

Comment: You can also check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/khushi13/pen/xzdZez) for a custom implementation of a lazy load dropdown.

Comment: Looks like your data might contain more than just `city` - why not chose to not annoy your users and first let them select a country, and then a city!